# org-mode cannot parse doi links correctly while `org-publish` to HTML

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Org-mode version 8.0.7 (release_8.0.7-387-gc2fa9)

I want the link `doi:10.1542/peds.2007-2361` to be exported as 
`<a href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1542/peds.2007-2361">doi:10.1542/peds.2007-2361</a>`. But I only get `<a href="10.1542/peds.2007-2361">10.1542/peds.2007-2361</a>`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at org-link-abbrev-alist?

Comment: `doi` is internal supported in org-mode 8.0.

Comment: I setup `(setq org-link-abbrev-alist '(("doi" . http://dx.doi.org/%s")))` and then get `<a href="http://dx.doi.org/%s">http://dx.doi.org/%s</a>`.